# Android RecyclerView search function

Tags: android, android-studio, dictionary, search, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a user manual application using android studio.
My app has a troubleshoot fragment. It displays list of problems that can be encountered by the product and he fragment also have a search function. The current search function uses "contains" method to search the list.

Example.
I have list of sentences in my recyclerview :

-No audio

-No power

-No display

**What it the best way to display "No audio" if I type "music" on the search function?** Is there a library I can use for this feature?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Maybe you can store the "music" word on a dictionary (list of words) like `no_audio_dict.txt` or anything that can store words. Then check the user's input if that exist on that dictionary, then you can display the word from your recyclerview like "No Audio" based on that case.

Comment: My current search feature is working but it only display "No audio" if I search for "audio". I just want to add functionality on my search like synonyms. "No audio" will display if I type "music" on the search.

Comment: @Tepits I see. I have to create a data dictionary for my keywords. Thank you for that information!